# I need to 2 levels of inheritance and abstraction in master-child relationship

Tags: c#, inheritance

Let's assume I have a business case I want to use some model to represent a master-child structure. And there will be certain classes to inherit from both the master class and child class.

I use the sample below

```
public abstract class BaseChild
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
}

public abstract class BaseMaster
{
    public abstract ReadOnlyCollection<BaseChild> Children { get; }
}
```

Now I need real classes to inherit from them. So have following

```
public class FirstRealChild : BaseChild
{
    public int AdditionalProperty { get; set; }
}

public class FirstRealMaster : BaseMaster
{
    public ReadOnlyCollection<FirstRealChild> Children { get; }
}
```

Of course it won't compile because of the error

> 'FirstRealMaster' does not implement inherited abstract member
>   'BaseMaster.Children.get'

I can remove the `public abstract ReadOnlyCollection<BaseChild> Children { get; }` from `BaseMaster` class, but it loses the constraint to all inherited classes that children are required.

Anybody has some better idea?

Comment: @Flaugzig not sure how it solves the problem, because the child's type is different.

Comment: True, my code review was a little to fast :)

Comment: *"there will be certain classes to inherit from both the master class and child class"* -- not in C#, there won't.

Comment: @EdPlunkett - you can read that two ways, i took it as "there will be certain classes to inherit from the master class and certain classes to inherit from the child class"

Comment: @HenkHolterman Good point. OP, if you didn't mean to suggest multiple inheritance, never mind!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may get somewhere with generics:

```
public abstract class BaseMaster<TChild> where TCHild : BaseChild
{
    // this probably doesn't have to be 'abstract' anymore
    public abstract ReadOnlyCollection<TChild> Children { get; }
}

public class FirstRealMaster : BaseMaster<FirstRealChild>
{
}
```

But we don't know enough about the relation between Master and Child classes to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Generics + potentially non-generic base class for your "with children" type is the standard solution. If you don't need `BaseMaster` to be assignment-compatible between different types of child nodes you can remove base non-generic class.

Something roughly like following:

```
public class BaseMaster
{
    public ReadOnlyCollection<BaseChild> Children { get; }
}

public class BaseMaster<T> : BaseMaster where T: BaseChild
{
    public new IEnumerable<T> Children { get
        {
           return base.Children.Cast<T>();
        };
    }
}
```