# Child/Parent inheritance/casting and Generic type

Tags: c#, inheritance

If I simply define the base class and inherited class this way

```
abstract class Base
{
}

class Inherited : Base
{
}
```

I am free to use `Base a = new Inherited();` without any error.

But if I have complicated base class with generic, for example see the code below:

```
abstract class AnotherBase<TDetailType> where TDetailType : AnotherDetail
{
    public List<TDetailType> Children { get; set; }
}

abstract class AnotherDetail
{
}
```

And I have inherited classes

```
class AnotherInherited : AnotherBase<AnotherInheritedDetail>
{
}

class AnotherInheritedDetail : AnotherDetail
{
}
```

Obviously I could not use the similar syntax any more `AnotherBase<AnotherDetail> b = new AnotherInherited();` because the compiler provides the error message

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'ConsoleApplication3.AnotherInherited' to
>   'ConsoleApplication3.AnotherBase'  ConsoleApplication3 c:\temp\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3\Program.cs  15  Active

Any suggestion how can I still use the base class to represent inherited classes under such circumstance?

Comment: Well you can still use `AnotherBase<AnotherInheritedDetail> b = new AnotherInherited()`

Comment: @JonSkeet, true I can do this way. But if I have more inherited classes there is no chance to use the same definition of `b` variable to work with them.

Comment: Well how would you expect to? What would the type of `b.Children` be?

Comment: Please see my discussion in Max Play's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Of course this would not work.

Your class `AnotherInherited` inherits from `AnotherBase<AnotherInheritedDetail>` and not `AnotherBase<AnotherDetail>`. This might seem wierd to you, but you are inheriting one class by another and not the generics aswell.

You may use the generics interchangable while working with the object, but the class-definition states only this one inheritance.

At least that is my understanding.

Comment: I see what you mean here. My whole problem started with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44833289/i-need-to-2-levels-of-inheritance-and-abstraction-in-master-child-relationship and I accepted the suggestion to come up with this model. But now the challenge is the inheritance. Maybe you can recommend some better design?

Comment: You could push the generic design in the inherited class aswell. I mean you can force it to be anything out of a few classes.

Comment: Yes I see the convenience from pushing the generic to inherited class. But on the other hand once I have the concrete class the type of the "children" is also defined. Thus I did not use generic in inherited class. Maybe it is a trade-off I have to balance.